# Get the region inside a box

Tags: opencv, box, outline

What function do i use to get the region inside a box or the outline just like in this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/txO9Q.png)

Edit: I actually meant was to find the region inside the black outline. Expected output(inside the red outline (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmDSN.png).
After having the ROI, I want to detect the shapes(https:// i. imgur.com/PVxKxuJ.png).

Solution:

1. Utilize `findContours` with a hierarchy of `RETR_EXTERNAL`. Unfortunately it will only result to the blue outline.
2. Using the the hierarchy `RETR_CCOMP` in `findContours` and selecting only the ROI with a hierarchy of `-1` finds the shape.

Comment: Your question is too broad, what are inputs available to you and what output do you expect, this single images conveys no information.

Comment: Sorry! Anyways, I'll just update the post for a clearer view. I may have solved this question